# How to remove forward slashes that are alone but not ones that are part of data?

Tags: sed

I have a file which contains dates in `mm/dd/yyyy` format, but there are also random "/" throughout the file that need to be removed which are alone and not connected to anything. I have tried `sed 's/[/]//g' file.txt` but this removes the slashes within the date, creating `mmddyyyy` dates that cannot be read later in the program. I'm looking for a way to remove the random forward slashes but preserve the ones contained within dates.

File looks like this

```
Date           Time    
05/23/2010     12:30    
05/23/2010     1:30    
/     
05/24/2010     1:30
```

And I want it to be

```
Date**         Time
05/23/2010     12:30    
05/23/2010     1:30    
05/24/2010     1:30
```

Comment: Please, show a proper testable sample with related expected output, don't post them as comments or images.

Comment: Do you mean you want to remove whole lines that only contain a `/`? Like `sed '/^\/$/d' file > newfile`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove all lines that only contain `/` from the file using

```sh
sed '/^\/$/d' file > newfile
```

Or, if there can be leading/trailing spaces, `'/^[[:blank:]]*\/[[:blank:]]*$/d'`.

See the [online `sed` demo](https://ideone.com/b9oNDa):

```sh
s='05/23/2010 12:30
05/23/2010 1:30
 / 
05/24/2010 1:30'
sed '/^[[:space:]]*\/[[:space:]]*$/d' <<< "$s"
```

Output:

```sh
05/23/2010 12:30
05/23/2010 1:30
05/24/2010 1:30
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk` it is much easier:

```sh
awk 'NR == 1 || $1 ~ /^([0-9]{2}\/){2}[0-9]{4}$/' file | column -t

Date        Time
05/23/2010  12:30
05/23/2010  1:30
05/24/2010  1:30
```

Here:

- `NR == 1`: Returns true if it is first record
- `||`: OR
- `$1 ~ /^([0-9]{2}\/){2}[0-9]{4}$/`: If first column matches given date format
- use default action to print matching records

Answer (score 0):

```
$ sed -nE  '1p;s/.*([0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{4} *[0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{2}).*/\1/p' file
```

Output:

```
Date           Time    
05/23/2010     12:30
05/23/2010     1:30
05/24/2010     1:30
```